# $T^{\ast}T$ unitary then $T$ isometry

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, inner-products, adjoint-operators, isometry

An operator $T$ is an isometry if $||Tf||=||f||$ for all $f$ in a Hilbert space $H$.

(a) Show that if $T$ is an isometry, then $<Tf,Tg>=<f,g>$ for every $f,g \in H$. Prove as result that $T^{\ast}T=I$
(b) If $T$ is an isometry and $T$ surjective, then $T$ is unitary and $TT^{\ast}=I$
(c) Give an example of an isometry that is not unitary
(d) Show that if $T^{\ast}T=I$ is unitary then $T$ is an isometry.

I have prove that (a) and $T^{\ast}T=I$.
$<f,g>=<Tf,Tg>=<f,T^{\ast}Tg> then T^{\ast}T=I.$

(b) For b, i have prove that $T$ is unitary, but not $TT^{\ast}=I.$
How prove $TT^{\ast}=I?$ I tried something similar to $T^{\ast}T=I$ but I do not get to the result.

(d) If $T^{\ast}T$ unitary I have this:

$||T^{\ast}Tf||=||f||$ then $<T^{\ast}Tf,T^{\ast}Tf>=<f,f>$
then $<Tf,(T^{\ast})^{\ast}T^{\ast}Tf>=<f,f>$ then $<f,T^{\ast}TT^{\ast}Tf>=<f,f>$
 This implies ¿$T^{\ast}TT^{\ast}T=I$ ?

How prove $T$ isometry?

Comment: I'm confused.  Are you trying to show that if $T^*T$ is unitary then $T$ is an isometry, or that if $T^*T=I$ then $T$ is an isometry?  The former requires (as far as I'm aware) a bit of machinery, while the latter is basically the definition.

Comment: If $T^{\ast}T$ is unitary then $T$ is isometry

Comment: Check page6 prop.2.3 from this book: Harmonic Analysis of Operators on Hilbert Space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(b):  If $T$ is an isometry, then it is injective, and by (a) $T^*T=I$.  If $T$ is a surjective isometry then it is invertible, and since $T^*$ is a right inverse it is *the* inverse of $T$, i.e., $T^*T=TT^*=I$.

(d):  If $T^*T$ is a unitary, then since it is also positive, we have $\sigma(T^*T)\subset S^1\cap[0,\infty)=\{1\}$ (here $S^1$ is the unit circle $\{|z|=1\}$ in $\mathbb C$).  By the continuous functional calculus, it follows that $T^*T=I$.  From here, we have 
$$\|f\|^2=\langle f,f\rangle=\langle T^*Tf,f\rangle=\langle Tf,Tf\rangle=\|Tf\|^2$$
for all $f\in H$, and therefore $T$ is an isometry.

Comment: Exists another proof more simply that T*T=I?

Comment: If $(T^{\ast}T)^2=I$ and $T^{\ast}T$ invertible, implies $T^{\ast}T=I$?

Comment: I'm not aware of a simpler proof, nor do I have reason to believe one should exist.  Nevertheless, if I think of one I'll let you know

Comment: I have this.
$T^{\ast}T$ is positive.
Let $\lambda$ eigenvalue of $T^{\ast}T$ with $v$ eigenvector , then $\lambda=\frac{\lambda <v,v>}{|v|^2}=\frac{<A^{\ast}Av,v>}{|v|^2}=\frac{<Av,Av>}{|v|^2}\geq 0$ then \lambda $\geq 0$ is real and no negative.

Now, $(T^{\ast}T)^2=I$ then with $v$ eigenvector, $v=(T^{\ast}T)^2v=\lambda^2v$
then $\lambda\in \left\{z:|z|=1\right\}$
Therefore if $\lambda$ is eigenvalue, $\lambda=1.$

Now, $T^{\ast}T$ is normal. How prove $T^{\ast}T=I$?

Comment: I understand that it should be by the Spectra Theorem for normal operators, but I have seen that this theorem is for finite dimension. In this case, that is not necessarily what I see.

According to me the Teo. Spectral tells me that if an operator is normal, then there is a base of eigenvectors for space.
Given that, in our case, with (e_k) the base of eigenvectors, $T^{\ast} Tv = T^{\ast} T (\sum_k e_k) = \sum_k T^{\ast} Te_k =\sum_k  \lambda e_k = \sum_k e_k = v$ (we already proved that $\lambda = 1$)

Comment: $T^*T$ is normal, and $\sigma(T^*T)=1$.  By the Gelfand-Naimark theorem, the unital $C^*$-algebra generated by $T^*T$ is isomorphic to $C(\sigma(T^*T))=\mathbb C$.  Both $I$ and $T^*T$ are mapped to $1$ under the Gelfand transform, but this is injective, so $T^*T=I$.